# Mongo aggregation - Sorting using a field value from previous pipeline as the sort field

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework, grouping

I have produced the below output using mongodb aggregation (including $group pipeline inside `levelsCount` field) :

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "First",
    "levelsCount" : [
        { "_id" : "level_One", "levelNum" : 1, "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "level_Three", "levelNum" : 3, "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "level_Four", "levelNum" : 4, "count" : 8 }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "name" : "Second",
    "levelsCount" : [
        { "_id" : "level_One", "levelNum" : 1, "count" : 5 },
        { "_id" : "level_Two", "levelNum" : 2, "count" : 2 },
        { "_id" : "level_Three", "levelNum" : 3, "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "level_Four", "levelNum" : 4, "count" : 3 }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "name" : "Third",
    "levelsCount" : [
        { "_id" : "level_One", "levelNum" : 1, "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "level_Two", "levelNum" : 2, "count" : 3 },
        { "_id" : "level_Three", "levelNum" : 3, "count" : 2 },
        { "_id" : "level_Four", "levelNum" : 4, "count" : 3 }
    ]
}
```

Now, I need to sort these documents based on the `levelNum` and `count` fields of `levelsCount` array elements. I.e. If two documents both had the count 5 for`levelNum: 1 (level_One)`, then the sort goes to compare the count of `levelNum: 2 (level_Two)` field and so on.

I see how [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline would work on multiple fields (Something like `{ $sort : { level_One : 1, level_Two: 1 } }`), But the problem is how to access those values of `levelNum` of each array element and set that value as a field name to do sorting on that. (I couldn't handle it even after [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)ing the `levelsCount` array).

**P.s:** The initial order of `levelsCount` array's elements may differ on each document and is not important.

**Edit:**
The expected output of the above structure would be:

```
// Sorted result:
{
    "_id" : "2",
    "name" : "Second",
    "levelsCount" : [
        { "_id" : "level_One", "levelNum" : 1, "count" : 5 }, // "level_One's count: 5"  is greater than "level_One's count: 1" in two other documents, regardless of other level_* fields. Therefore this whole document with "name: Second" is ordered first.
        { "_id" : "level_Two", "levelNum" : 2, "count" : 2 },
        { "_id" : "level_Three", "levelNum" : 3, "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "level_Four", "levelNum" : 4, "count" : 3 }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "3",
    "name" : "Third",
    "levelsCount" : [
        { "_id" : "level_One", "levelNum" : 1, "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "level_Two", "levelNum" : 2, "count" : 3 }, // "level_Two's count" in this document exists with value (3) while the "level_Two" doesn't exist in the below document which mean (0) value for count. So this document with "name: Third" is ordered higher than the below document.
        { "_id" : "level_Three", "levelNum" : 3, "count" : 2 },
        { "_id" : "level_Four", "levelNum" : 4, "count" : 3 }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "First",
    "levelsCount" : [
        { "_id" : "level_One", "levelNum" : 1, "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "level_Three", "levelNum" : 3, "count" : 1 },
        { "_id" : "level_Four", "levelNum" : 4, "count" : 8 }
    ]
}
```

Of course, I'd prefer to have an output document in the below format, But the first problem is to sort all docs:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "name" : "First",
    "levelsCount" : [
        { "level_One" : 1 },
        { "level_Three" : 1 },
        { "level_Four" : 8 }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Provide please expected result in json

Comment: @Valijon The expected result is added to the question. Thanks for following up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by `levelNum` as descending order and `count` as ascending order,

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      "levelsCount.levelNum": -1,
      "levelsCount.count": 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vyNZy9OeYOi)

---

For key-value format result of `levelsCount` array,

- `$map` to iterate loop of `levelsCount` array
- prepare key-value pair array and convert to object using `$arrayToObject`

```
  {
    $addFields: {
      levelsCount: {
        $map: {
          input: "$levelsCount",
          in: {
            $arrayToObject: [
              [{ k: "$$this._id", v: "$$this.levelNum" }]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YrjgQiKsRlz)

Comment: Thanks a lot.I faced 2 issues during tests: **1.** If the `levelsCount` array in a document doesn't have a document with the value `level_Two` for `levelsCount._id` field; the sort will order that document higher than the one that has the actual `level_Two` value for its `levelsCount._id`. Whereas I need the absent document to get treated as `0` value for its `count` field which will cause a lower place in order. **2.** The values of`levelsCount._id` are actually strings that their alphabetic sorting will be conceptually incorrect.So I needed to add an extra field with the correspondent number

Comment: I've edited the input documents in the question

Comment: i don't think its possible, may be need to `$unwind` deconstruct array but definitely it will change the order of actual array elements in `levelsCount`.

Comment: The initial order of the elements in the `levelsCount` list doesn't matter really

Comment: Maybe inserting `levelsCount._id` with missing values inside `levelsCount` array artificially? something like `{ "_id" : "level_Two", "levelNum" : 2, "count" : 0 }` with `count : 0` for sorting. but I don't how.

Comment: can you verify this order [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vyNZy9OeYOi)

Comment: YES! That works correctly. However, I don't get why the `levelsCount.levelNum` is descending while we intend this order: `1,2,3,4`. The same ambiguity is for `levelsCount.count`; Why is that sorting ascending while we need this order: `4,3,2,1`. For me, It seems the sort order of these two fields should be swapped logically, but not sure why are working currently.

Comment: updated, *I don't get why the levelsCount.levelNum is descending*, because it order by greater number when we direct sort by field that is in array of object.

Comment: Any documents for this thing? : _because it order by greater number when we direct sort by field that is in array of object._ I didn't see about that in [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) documentation

Comment: it means in your case 1) `levelNum: -1` it will check last to first and order would be (first, second, third) 2) `levelNum: -1 && count: 1` it will check count is nearest to levelNum so it would be (second, third, first), so i am not sure if above query is correct as per your expectation, the result would be different if we unwind array.. like [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Nl8tW0TTlny) because it will check element by element.